# How to link to a delegate within a C block of code

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I have both C code and Objective-C code in my cocoa view controller. I currently link the two by making a reference to the objective-c self with a global self variable that I then use to access within C.

This works when I want to call an Objective-C method from my C block of code.
But now I am trying to access a property through my c code like so `[selfGlobal delegate]` but this is returning null at run time.

What is the correct way to reference to my delegate property?

Here is my code and my debugger output showing the expected output from the code in my Objective-C block, and also showing the unexpected output when I try to make a link to my delegate within C, remember that this does work when I call a method but not when I attempt to make a link to the delegate property.

**Objective-C block of code which logs the expected output:**

```
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate withWindow:(NSWindow*)aWindow{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        delegate = aDelegate;
        NSLog(@"delegate: %@", delegate);

        window = aWindow;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Here's how I make calls to my delegate method within an Objective-C method:**

```
SEL selector = @selector(PKFPSetProgressMaxCount:);
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    [delegate PKFPSetProgressMaxCount:maxEnrollCount];
}
```

**and here's how I try to link to my delegate within the C function being run in the background thread. I also try to log out the value of the delegate property while I am debugging**

```
 NSLog(@"enroll, selfglobal delegate: %@", [selfGlobal delegate]);
if([selfGlobal delegate]){
    NSLog(@"delegate is not empty");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"delegate is empty");
}

SEL selector = @selector(PKFPDidReceiveActionMessage:);
if ([[selfGlobal delegate] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"delegate does have PKFPDidReceiveActionMessage in it");

    [[selfGlobal delegate] PKFPDidReceiveActionMessage:@"Say a word"];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"delegate does not have PKFPDidReceiveActionMessage in it");

}
```

And this is the output I am getting in the debugger.

```
//Values from ref 1
init method called
window did load method called
delegate: <MainScreenWC: 0x610000124c40>

init device method called

//Ref 2
-[MainScreenWC PKFPSetProgressMaxCount:]

 //These are calls made moments before the c function is called in the
-[MainScreenWC enrollUser:]
-[MainScreenWC PKFPSetUIControlsEnabled:] enableUIControls: 0

 //Ref 3 - This is inside the C function, and the delegate is returning null
 enroll, selfglobal delegate: (null)
 delegate is empty
 delegate does not have PKFPDidReceiveActionMessage in it
```

Can someone help out please?

**UPDATE 1**

`id selfGlobal;` is being set in the same file where the protocol is created.

Here is the C function that I am trying to access the delegate from within.

```
void FTR_CBAPI UserCallBack(
                            FTR_USER_CTX Context,
                            FTR_STATE StateMask,
                            FTR_RESPONSE *pResponse,
                            FTR_SIGNAL Signal,
                            FTR_BITMAP_PTR pBitmap)
{
    //This method is automatically called by the API that I am working with. 
    //I need to have access to the Objective-C delegate variable from within this code block, but the delegate is returning null only in here.
    ...

}
```

Comment: Please, please, copy your code instead of showing screenshots.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you start your threads, too. I'm a little surprised that you decided to use a global variable considering that threads can receive arguments.

Comment: I'm using a global variable since the C function is a callback function from an API, so changing the variables - I'm sure - will prevent the call back function from being called.

Comment: Ok ok guys, sheesh, I didnt know it was that bad to upload images. Sorry, I have updated the post, now Please, please undo those down votes so we can get the show on the road again.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you still haven't shown how you start the thread nor where the global variable is set.

Comment: Relax guys, I've taken down the pictures a long time back and have already replaced it with textual code instead.

Comment: @zneak Thanks for commenting, but please do read the post carefully buddy. I have already stated that the code is writtin in callback function which has been setup by an SDK which cannot be edited hence the global variable so I can access self. If you must see the method structure, I have posted an update for you buddy. Pls do check it out.

Comment: Could it be that the `selfGlobal` variable is not being updated along with the delegate propterty? This is what I initially thought, so I set the `selfGlobal` to `self` only after the delegate was set hoping that it would copy that property over too.. but thats not the case. Just sharing my thoughts on this situation

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to manually synthesize the delegate property, for some reason it didnt like the automatic synthesize. If someone can shed some light on why that is the case, then please do edit this post to add more information.

I am now getting the correct output:

```
delegate is not empty
delegate does have PKFPDidReceiveActionMessage in it
-[MainScreenWC PKFPDidReceiveActionMessage:] actionMessage: Say a word
```